# checking if the user input has changed from the previous input

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Hi I am new to programming

I have a masked textbox into which a user inputs an account number, then I have a label which displays the number of users or rather display the number of times the account number has been changed. I.e. as each account number is being entered the customer count should increase.

I don't have an example code because I do not even know where to start

Please show me how to code this, I am using a form in Visual Studio

Comment: You can simply add textChanged event by just double clicking your textBox

Answer (score 0):

have it add the input to a list or array, and then you can run a check to see if the array/list contains that input already. If so, do not add the input again, if it does not, then add the input. You can then tell how many customers you have by the size of the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you are taking in the users input as a string do a String Comparison or if you're doing strictly a numerical account number and am taking it in as an int then simply see if the numbers are different

For strings use:

```
result = input1.Equals(input2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

For ints just use an If statement to test:

```
if(input1 != input2) {
 Console.WriteLine("Input has changed")
  else
 Console.WriteLine("Input has not changed");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the user has to push a button after the user has entered the password? If so, we can easily track this. First we make a global `int` variable like so: `private int userCount = 0;`
Then we add an event to our button:

```
private void btnAccountNumber_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    userCount = userCount + 1; 
    displayLabel.Text = userCount.ToString() + " Customers";
    maskedTextBox.Clear();
}
```

So in this button we add our customer that just clicked on our button to the total of users.
Next we show that number in the label you created. And finally we clear the maskedTextBox of userInput so the next customer can use it.